# how to disable clicks under android constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have an activity layout which had reyclerview list and on click on filter button another layout opens above it but the problem is when click on white space on the filter layout it make click on the hidden item in the recyclerview which hidden under it so how can I make no action happens on clicking on white space on the filter layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this atrr to your group layout **constraintlayout** your top layer parent

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

this atrr will make your layout(Top) click able and avoid click white space to bottom layout

-- hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Try these line

```
constrainlayout.setenabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you show the xml file for more info?
first put the recycler view under the filter layout.
after that set filter layout visibility to gone. when filter button clicked, set filter layout visibility from gone to visible.
your recycler view must be under filter layout in visible mode